# Unable to import flask app folder in unittest folder of an repo

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, flask

I am facing issues in writing unit test for my flask app. Exact issue is that test files in unit-test directory is not able to import files from app folder.
My directory structure:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── api.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── docker
│   ├── docker-compose.yml
│   └── start.sh
├── requirements.txt
└── unit-test
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_api.py
```

Code in unit-test/test_api.py:

```
import unittest
from app import api
```

Absolute import throws this error:
`from app import api`
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`

I have tried the following after checking a few resources of absolute and relative imports, none of them worked.

```
from .. import app
```

error:
`from .. import app`
`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`
I checked a few questions on SO and someone recommended having _*init*_.py file in the `unit-test` folder as well but I already have a blank init.py file there.
I have reviewed numerous blogs and youtube tutorials and absolute imports work for them easily.
Please advise how to fix this error and run unit tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/the/required/folder')
import name_of_file
```

if not an inbuilt package, Python only searches in the current directory when you try to import, thus we have to add this path, so that it looks inside this particular folder as well. After adding that, you can simply do the import.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Is this path the complete path or the relative path? If it is the complete local path, I think it would fail if somebody else runs the unittests? Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Its the relative path

Comment: ok, I tried it like this:
```
import sys 
sys.path.append('../app')
import api
```
but it's still failing to import api. Please advise what am I doing wrong as per the mentioned directory structure.

Comment: https://blog.finxter.com/python-how-to-import-modules-from-another-folder/#:~:text=The%20most%20Pythonic%20way%20to,import%20module%20.

(This link will help)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I had method 3 already implemented but it was not working. I implemented method 1 and replaced it with method 3 and now it is working.